# Having trouble reading some charts (SBMG-SBLO)

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, aeronautical-charts, vor, radio-navigation

I'm a flight sim user practicing instrument navigation with a short and apparently simple flight, SBMG to SBLO (South America). The distance between the two airports is 49.5 nautical miles (the simulator tells me). My simulator is X-Plane 11. The aircraft is the Cessna 172.

I've flown the mentioned flight a couple of times, but I'm afraid I am making mistakes. There are a couple of questions I'd like to make.

Let's start with this [SBMG SID chart](http://ais.decea.gov.br/download/?arquivo=dac514bf-8f4c-4a0e-ac0d7e50631a0ee7&apikey=1587263166) *(these charts come from [AISWEB](https://www.aisweb.aer.mil.br/?i=cartas))*. The path with red dots is the one I'm following.

[image: SBMG SID chart]

(1) You see `096 >` on the first 3 nautical miles? Does it mean I should track course `096` on the `LON` VOR right after takeoff, or is it just the heading I should be on for the first 3 nautical miles? You see, I'm having trouble figuring out what is the reference navigation aid for these headings/radials.

(2) After passing MG123, I start to track the `100` radial on the `LON` VOR for 47 nautical miles. After 47 miles I switch to the approach chart. Is that correct?

---

The next chart is a [IAC for SBLO](http://ais.decea.gov.br/download/?arquivo=7d4f1195-4a12-4b5e-9913b03f447fda9a&apikey=1587263166). It has a VOR/DME arc.

[image: SBLO IAC chart]

(3) I am still tracking `100` towards `LON`, but the nearest entry point for the arc is `090`. After 47 nautical miles, I am too close to SBLO to change my course, and it's time to enter the arc already. I feel I missed something.

Comment: Well, for one thing that MG123 waypoint is an RNAV waypoint, you cannot fly that route using conventional VOR/DMEs you would have in a Cessna.You need to be at least B-RNAV capable, then track 096 to MG123 followed by 100 to LON (which just so happens to be a VOR but does not need to)

Comment: The VOR chart is indeed a conventional one, but it does not match your route. You either need to find a transition of some sort, radar vectors, or self-position (using RNAV) to Ceila which is your Initial Fix

Comment: For an Approach, it is perfectly fine to enter the approach anytime between the IAF and the FAF. Typically, this is done by radar vectors from ATC. Otherwise, you should stay above the MSA until you are established on a published leg. Under radar vectors, ATC can get you as close to the airport as the Intermediate Leg. Once established On the Intermediate Leg, you will be lined up for alignment with the Final Approach Leg.

Comment: Be very aware of the altitude difference between the MSA and the crossing altitude of your fixes. And, if the IAP has a TAA, you are technically established on the approach if you follow the TAA.

Comment: Also, the link you have on your question is to an RNAV SID. You would just follow the magenta line. There is no VOR radial that you need to track. The VOR acts as another GPS waypoint. You are tracking from waypoint to waypoint. You have to switch from RNAV to VOR radio navigation if you want to subsequently fly the VOR Z RWY 13. That means abandoning the SID early. Or, flying all the way to the VOR before starting the published approach.

Comment: @Radu094 - Celia is marked IF (Intermediate Fix). If it were an Initial Approach Fix, it would be marked either IAF or IF/IAF.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It seems I have a lot to learn before attempting these procedures. Do you recommend any specific material that covers instrument navigation thoroughly?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is usually unwise to join the Approach on the Intermediate leg unless you are being radar vectored by ATC due to the difference in altitude between the MSA and the crossing altitudes for the FAF. As far as thorough material...

Comment: Pilots Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge.  
Airplane Flying Handbook.  
Instrument Flying Handbook.  
Instrument Procedures Handbook.   
Digital Terminal Procedures  Supplemental.  
Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide.  
Terminal Procedure Publications.  
Flight Navigator Handbook.  
Advanced Avionics Handbook.

Comment: @crimson_king  - All of these can be found for free online.

Comment: @DeanF. ouch, you are right about Ceila , that is an IF. Well, unless there are other parts of the chart missing, it will still work if he reached Ceila at 5000' then descend to Edpud in 2nm..a bit steep for a jet, but a Cessna can do that no problem

Comment: alternatively, provided you are cleared that way, once <11 Dme LON you can turn left and establish on the 10 Dme arc, descending from 5000' to 4100', turn right at Ceila( after crossing R297) and just continue on the procedure. It would be legal and doable provided ATC is aware of your intentions and has cleared you

Comment: @Radu094 - You are exactly right. The approach can be picked up anywhere before the FAF. I cautioned the OP against it in general unless being radar vectored because the difference in MSA and the FAF crossing altitude could be too great to affect a reasonable and stable descent. This particular IAP should pose no problems for a Cessna, though. I’ve had ATC keep me higher than this for traffic up until the very last possible minute. It was in VMC on a practice procedure, though. Self-vectoring in IMC normally would not be advised without doing the full procedure. VMC is doable, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting academic exercise crimson_king. I don’t think you would get cleared for or use this SID/IAP combo. The airports are too close together. You are basically using your destination airport’s NavAid as the *beginning/start* of your departure. You will overfly the airport before you get to the VOR that starts the procedure. Then, you would have to backtrack out to the arc, using LON as your IAF.

The plate that you referenced is just an instruction on how to get to the start of your departure. There is probably a textual ODP to go with it. If you were in IMC, you would remain under radar vectors and ATC control the entire time. They would probably give you instructions like: Fly runway heading climb and maintain 5000 radar vectors direct D270L cleared the VOR Z Runway 13. This is of course abbreviated since you would have a switch of ATC from tower to approach.

Based on the information provided, For the purposes of simming, your best bet is to:

1. Take off from the runway of predominant wind.
2. Remain in the traffic pattern and climb over the airport.
3. Climb until you are at 5000 feet or more. The reason for this is that the only altitude information I see on the plate are the Minimum Sector Altitude and the Maximum Elevation Figures.
4. Fly direct to MG123 using RNAV/GPS.
5. Switch to VLOC/VOR mode
6. Fly direct to D270L.
7. Begin your IAP

   A second option is to just fly direct to LON using your Nav radio by the shortest route possible. Use MG123 as a fly over reference point. Maintain full throttle at Vx until 5000 feet. Once you are within 12 miles DME of LON. Start your descent down to 4100 feet. Join the arc wherever you happen to enter.

Celia is not marked as an IF/IAF. So, I would avoid going directly there. It would be a perfectly good option if you were being radar vectored and cleared there by ATC.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will study the information you gave me once I catch up on the required missing pieces of knowledge. It's been a couple of years since my last simulator flight. I'm just a programmer who's enthusiastic about aviation!

Comment: @crimson_king - No problem. You might start with US FAA charts and plates first. I am biased for them since they are what I first learned. They seemed to contain more explicit detail in a clearer format than the charts you linked. You can get them free from many online sources like https://skyvector.com/  and  https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/